# How do I mock a specific attribute on a model for a Rails view test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, null-object-pattern

I'm writing tests for a rails view, lets say the view is something like:

**show.json.rep**

```
r.element :user, @user do |u|
    r.element :id, u.id
    r.element :somefield1, u.somefield1
    // a lot of fields here
    r.element :somefield100, u.somefield100
end
```

Now I want to test the json it generates and just interest in the `id` field.

If my test code is written like:

```
describe "show.json.rep" do
   it "will generate json with correct id" do
       assign(:user, mock(:user, :id=>111))
       render
       puts "######### generate json:"
       puts rendered
       ...
   end
end
```

It will reports such an error:

```
Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Mock :user received unexpected message :somefield1 with (no args)
```

I don't want to mock all the fields like `somefieldX` that I don't interest, so I tried the `as_null_object`:

```
describe "show.json.rep" do
   it "will generate json with correct id" do
       assign(:user, mock(:user, :id=>111).as_null_object)
       render
       puts "######### generate json:"
       puts rendered
       ...
   end
end
```

This time, it doesn't report that error, but the strange thing is, the `rendered` value is `null`!!

```
######### generate json:
null
```

I'm not sure why and how to fix it? Or is there any other way to let me just provide the field I interest?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `id` when creating the object and then calling [as_null_object](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object) will cause the id (and any other method) to return nil.

> Use the as_null_object method to ignore any messages that aren't
>   explicitly set as stubs or message expectations.

This is how you would stub the `id` method:

```
require 'json'

describe "show.json.rep" do

   let(:user) { double("User").as_null_object }
   let(:json) { JSON.parse(rendered).symbolize_keys! }

   before(:each) do
     allow(user).to receive(:id).and_return(666)
     assign(:user, user)
     render
   end

   it "will generate json with correct id" do
       expect(json[:id]).to equal (user.id)
   end
end
```

But in the long run you should probably be using [fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) or [factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) rather than setting up doubles all over your tests. 
I also prefer using [ActiveModel serializers](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast) because they are much easier and faster to test since you are not encoding and the parsing JSON.

**Edit:**

Another solution is to use `User.new`

```
let(:user) { User.new(id: 666) }
```